# How can I iterate over this Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the object:

```
var IOBreadcrumb = function () {
    this.breadcrumbs = [];
    this.add = function(title, url) {
      var crumb = {
        title: title, 
        url:url
      };
      this.breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
    };
  };
```

Lets say I add 3 items to breadcrumbs:

```
IOBreadcrumb.add('a',a);
IOBreadcrumb.add('b',b);
IOBreadcrumb.add('c',c);
```

How can I iterate over this and print out the title, and the url?

Comment: You can't call the `add` method directly on `IOBreadcrumb`, since this is just a *constructor function*, you need to create an object: `var obj = new IOBreadcrumb(); obj.add('a', a);`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a method

```
print = function(){
   for (var i = 0; i < this.breadcrumbs.length; i++) {
       var current = this.breadcrumbs[i];
       console.log(current.title, current.url);
   }
}
```

to your IOBreadcrumb object, and then just invoke it

`IOBreadcrumb.print();`

Comment: It seems like it's more likely that he will be displaying this in an HTML page, in which case he should just add this as a `toString` function and return the result.

Comment: sure, he can do whatever he wants.  but his question said 'print', so i gave the simplest possible example.

Comment: The question is more about how to iterate than it is how to print.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `each` method:

```
var IOBreadcrumb = function IOBreadcrumb() {
    this.breadcrumbs = [];
    this.add = function(title, url) {
      var crumb = {
        title: title, 
        url:url
      };
      this.breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
    };

    this.each = function(callback) {
       for (var i = 0; i < this.breadcrumbs.length; i++) {
           callback(this.breadcrumbs[i]);
       }
    }

  };
```

And use it like this:

```
var ioBc = new IOBreadcrumb();
ioBc.add('a',a);
ioBc.add('b',b);
ioBc.add('c',c);

ioBc.each(function(item) {
    console.log(item.title + ' ' + item.url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jason's answer is almost there. The only improvement is that there is no need to implement your own `each` function if you're using jquery.

```
var ioBc = new IOBreadcrumb();
ioBc.add('a',a);
ioBc.add('b',b);
ioBc.add('c',c);

$.each(ioBc.breadcrumbs, function(item) {
    console.log(item.title + ' ' + item.url);
});
```

At the very least you should use `$.each` from your `each` function if you don't want callers to access `breadcrumbs` directly

```
...
this.each = function(callback) {
   $.each(this.breadcrumbs, callback);
}
...
```

Comment: what happens if he wanted to use this object somewhere where jQuery wasn't available? having a for loop instead of the $.each call is worth having the flexibility, IMO.

Comment: The question is tagged as jquery, I'm answering the user's question

Comment: @JasonMiesionczek: In any case, my real point is that the way you've coded it, you'd have to duplicate the looping code everywhere you need to iterate through an array (on other objects). If you don't have jQuery, at least you should create your own `each` function, instead of duplicating that logic everywhere it's needed.

Comment: if he is using this on multiple objects, then i would agree jquery is the better option, but for the case of this single object, i don't think it is necessary.

Comment: It's very easy to see this being used on other objects. If something is clearly not specific to an object, I'd rather put it where it belongs, encouraging code reuse in the future